# syntax error with string templates

Tags: javascript

I have a Node.js configuration file config.json as such:

```
{       
"apiPrefix":"http://localhost:8080",
"serverPort":"8080",
"db":{
    "name":"notes",
    "host":"localhost",
    "port":"27017"
    } 
}
```

When I try to connect to the MongoDB database:

```
    import config from '../../etc/config.json';

   export function setUpConnection(){
        console.log(config.db);
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://${config.db.host}:${config.db.port}/${config.db.name}');
    }
```

But my server does not connect to the database, unless I write the URI address literally as follows:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/notes');
```

What is wrong with my syntax ${} ? 
In console.log I see this

```
{ name: 'notes', host: 'localhost', port: '27017' }
```

Comment: `'mongodb://${config.db.host}:${config.db.port}/${config.db.name}'` is a literal ... you need backticks ... `\`mongodb://${config.db.host}:${config.db.port}/${config.db.name}\`` to use such string templates

Comment: Sorry for my english in russian it sounds sintacsys ))

Comment: what is a difference ?

Comment: it's all good regarding the word, I figured that's what you meant - see comment for answer though - you're trying to use template literals, but using the wrong `'`

Comment: difference? see [documentation on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Good I see Thank you very much